# Streaming http response does not show full contents

Tags: django

I am creating a website using `django`. I load web pages using `StreamingHttpResponse`, more information is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/).

My `views` code:

```
from django.http.response import StreamingHttpResponse    

class SearchNews:
    def get(self, request):
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(self._load_stream(request))
        return response

    def _load_stream(self, request):
        query = request.GET.get('query', '')
        yield loader.get_template('news_results_part1.html').render({
            'request': request,
            'query': query,
        })
        api = SearchNews()
        results = api.search(query)
        yield loader.get_template('news_results_part2.html').render({
            'request': request,
            'query': query,
            'results': results,
        })
```

I have two html parts, first part only includes header and the second part contains the search results.

The first html part code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>
        {{ query }}
    </title>

    <style>
        {% include 'internal_static/css/search_results.css' %}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="border-bottom clearfix">
        <div class="max-width-large w-100 padding-left-lg">
            {% include 'header.html' with query=query %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the second html part code:

```
    <div>
        {% if extra_info.correct_query %}
            <div class="correct-query-wrapper padding-left-lg max-width-large pt-3 clear-both w-100 text-right">
                <span class="float-right text-danger">did you mean?</span>
                <span class="p-2 font-italic">
                    <a href="{% url 'search' %}?query={{ correct_query }}">
                        {{ correct_query }}
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="padding-left-lg clearfix result-cart-wrapper max-width-large clear-both">
            {% include 'result_carts.html' with query=query %}
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the project in `localhost` everything is ok and browser shows the full contents of the first part and after receiving search results shows the second part. But when I deploy the project in the server, browser shows only a little part of the first part and after receiving the second part completes the first part and shows the second part together.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `nginx` configuration. I had to disable buffering in `nginx` by adding two these lines:

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

The full `nginx` configuration file is like this:

```
server {
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_request_buffering off;

                add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;
        }

}
```